# Reading Postgres geometry into byte[] with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, geometry

I'm trying to read a PostGIS geometry column and save it as a Java `byte[]` with hibernate.

As far as I know I should be storing it in Java the way it's represented in `psql`.

I manage to write it and even see it within `psql` but when I read it with the wkbreader - I get the following error:

> com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException: Unknown WKB type 48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGIS [exports a `ST_AsBinary` function](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_AsBinary.html) or (if you want to preserve SRID) [`ST_AsEWKB`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_AsEWKB.html).

You should store the results of this function, rather than trying to cast the display representation, and then load with `ST_GeomFromWKB` or `ST_GeomFromEWKB` (depending on whether you used the AsBinary or AsEWKB form on output).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error resolved by upgrading the JDBC driver version.  I'm able to able to read PostGIS geometry into JTS with the following:

Query:

```
SELECT ST_AsBinary(geom) FROM mytable;
```

Code:

```
// myWKBReader is a JTS WKBReader
// myResultSet is a JDBC ResultSet
Geometry geom = myWKBReader.read(myResultSet.getBytes("st_asbinary"));
```

POM:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command as Postgres

```
ALTER DATABASE table SET bytea_output TO 'escape';
```

then restart Postgres.